How to append to 'db' in Dell 3140's UEFI Firmware from within UEFI Setup
I have Dell 3140 Laptop with UEFI and Windows 11.
I have downloaded the new windows uefi ca 2023.crt certificate from Microsoft.
I want to append the same to 'db' variable. The UEFI offers the required interface. I have enabled Audit Mode and then Custom Mode in the firmware setup under Secure Boot options to allow me to do that.
See the screenshots. The process appears simple, select 'db' option. Click append from file
Select the .crt file and Submit.
The thing is after doing this, it apparently does nothing. It does not report success or failure. It also does not show any pending changes applicable, still I click Apply Changes button.
Booting into Windows 11 I run the following Powershell command as admin and it returns False indicating that there's no such variable in db.
 [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetString((Get-SecureBootUEFI db).bytes) -match "Windows UEFI CA 2023"

I tried converting .crt to base64 CER as well as Der encoded CER but same result.
Unfortunately, Internet has no references. I am not too sure what am I missing.
I also tried Deploy mode but nothing changed.
I also tried doing the same thing after turning off secure boot but again nothing changed.
UEFI version is latest. No further updates available.
Any further suggestions would be great.



Is there a way to install your own PK, then? If you can use your own PK, then you could use that to install a custom KEK from within Deploy mode, and then do the same using your own KEK to update db.
